# How can I set an environment variable as gulp task?

Tags: node.js, gulp, environment-variables

I don't want type the extra arguments `NODE_ENV='production' gulp` every time I run gulp to set an environment variable.

I would rather set the environment variable **from within gulp via a task**.

What would be a good way to achieve this?

Comment: use `yargs` &  `gulp-constatnt` to generate the files having `env` based on command line arguments passed

Answer (score 143, accepted):

```
gulp.task('set-dev-node-env', function() {
    return process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
});

gulp.task('set-prod-node-env', function() {
    return process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
});
```

Use it like:

```
gulp.task('build_for_prod', ['set-prod-node-env'], function() {
    // maybe here manipulate config object  
    config.paths.src.scripts = config.paths.deploy.scripts;
    runSequence(
        'build',
        's3'
    );
});
```

Comment: Right answer that shows how to accomplish simple task without excessive dependencies

Comment: does this still work? I'm on osx where it doesn't :(

Comment: Sorry it turned out to be a logical error on my end. Can you edit the answer so I can change my vote to up? :) @EliseChant

Comment: Can someone explain the line `config.paths.src.scripts = config.paths.deploy.scripts;` in relation to detecting environment vars?

Comment: Another easier way is gulp-mode plugin. More details at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68110717/10457393) post.

Answer (score 22):

You can also define it as a script in your `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "scripts": {
    "gulp": "NODE_ENV='development' gulp",
    "gulp-build": "NODE_ENV='production' gulp"
  },
  ...
}
```

And run it with `npm run gulp-build`. This has a few benefits

- You can define arguments easily instead of typing them every time
- Global gulp installation isn't required (same for other tools, like webpack)
- You can define multiple variants with different environment variables and(or) arguments without changing the gulpfile (as you can see above - gulp and gulp-build for development and production respectively)

Comment: Great answer. I think it is so important to try to leverage what you already have, before introduction another tool into the mix!

Answer (score 17):

Try [gulp-env](https://github.com/moveline/gulp-env)

Quick example on how to set some environment variables before running the nodemon task:

```
// gulpfile.js

var gulp = require('gulp');
var nodemon = require('nodemon');
var env = require('gulp-env');

gulp.task('nodemon', function() {
    // nodemon server (just an example task)
});

gulp.task('set-env', function () {
  env({
    vars: {
      MONGO_URI: "mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb-for-british-eyes-only",
      PORT: 9001
    }
  })
});

gulp.task('default', ['set-env', 'nodemon'])
```

Comment: When I run this, I get `MONGO_URI is not defined`

Comment: The native Node way is probably the best as shown in other answers on this post. ` return process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';`

Answer (score 3):

You can Setup the environment like follows:

```
// Environment Setup
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
```

Then you can use the environment to process the code as follows:

```
gulp.task('js',function(){
gulp.src(jsPath)
.pipe(browserify({debug: env === 'development'}))
.pipe(gulpif(env === 'production' , uglify()))
.pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also set one by default, and read the variables from a `json` file:

```
gulp.task('set-env', function () {
    var envId = gutil.env.env;
    if (!envId) {
      envId = "dev";
    }
    genv({
        file: "env." + envId + ".json"
    });
});
```

This would be always `dev` env by default, and you could call it setting another env, like this:

`gulp --env prod`

More of [gulp-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-env)