# Set gulp tasks depending on NODE_ENV

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Is there a way to specify a gulp task depending on the `NODE_ENV` that is set?

For example in my `package.json` file, I have something like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "gulp"
 }
```

And I have multiple `gulp` tasks

```
gulp.task('development', function () {
   // run dev related tasks like watch 
});

gulp.task('production', function () {
   // run prod related tasks
});
```

If I set `NODE_ENV=production npm start`, can I specify to only run `gulp production`? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did any of these answers help you? Please vote and accept or comment if you are still having the issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using a single ternary in your default gulp task, you can have something like:

```
gulp.task('default',
  [process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development']
);
```

You will then be able to keep the single `gulp` command in your `package.json` and using this like you said:

```
NODE_ENV=production npm start
```

Any other value of your `NODE_ENV` variable will launch the `development` task.

---

You could of course do an advanced usage using an object allowing for multiple tasks and avoiding `if` trees hell:

```
var tasks = {
  development: 'development',
  production: ['git', 'build', 'publish'],
  preprod: ['build:preprod', 'publish:preprod'],
  ...
}

gulp.task('default', tasks[process.env.NODE_ENV] || 'fallback')
```

Keep in mind that when giving an array of tasks, they will be run in parallel.

Comment: "tasks[process.env.NODE_ENV]' <-- Cool

Comment: @jjalonso Glad you like it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have your first gulp task run other gulp tasks based on the `process.env.NODE_ENV` value.

```
gulp.task('launcher', function(){
  switch (process.env.NODE_ENV){
    case 'development':
      // Run dev tasks from here
      break;
    case 'production':
      // Run prod tasks
      break;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The other simple way could be

```
gulp.task('set-dev-env', function () {
    return process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
});

gulp.task('set-prod-env', function () {
    return process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
});

gulp.task('development', ['set-dev-env'], function () {
    // your code
});

gulp.task('production', ['set-prod-env'], function () {
    // your code
});
```

Run `gulp production` or `gulp development`.

Comment: That helped! For gulp4 I used:

const setProdEnv = (cb) => {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'
  cb()
}

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [gulp-mode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-mode) plugin.

Usage:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var mode = require('gulp-mode')();
    var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

    gulp.task('default', function() {
      gulp.src('src/*.js')
          .pipe(mode.production(uglify()))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    });
```

OR

```
    var isProduction = mode.production();
    if (isProduction) {
        console.log("Production mode");
    }
```

Start build as:

```
gulp build --production
```

For "npm run-script" use-cases:

```
package.json :-
    "scripts": {
        "devbld": "gulp build --development",
        "prodbld": "gulp build --production",
      }

    $ npm run devbld
    $ npm run prodbld
```

Answer (score -3):

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production")
  // whatever
```