# call gulp task with process.env.NODE_ENV argument

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

Can I set process.env.NODE_ENV when task is called?

I wrote in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "clean" : "gulp clean:build --env production"
}
```

Also I tried `--NODE_ENV=production` but it doesn't work. process.env.NODE_ENV is undefined.

Comment: if you're on a unix-y system you can do `NODE_ENV=production gulp clean: build` as the command.  There's probably an equivalent for windows

Comment: Another easier method requiring lot less typing possible with gulp-mode plugin. Detailed at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68110717/10457393) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can just set the variable like in the windows command prompt.

```
set NODE_ENV=production
```

So for your script `package.json` something like this:

```
"scripts": {
   "clean" : "set NODE_ENV=production && gulp clean:build --env production"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In WebStorm I can set environment in settings menu.

But I wonder how to write environment in package.json/scripts.

[image]