# How can I set NODE_ENV?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp

I am using gulp in my reactjs solution and want to set the NODE_ENV, I tried this:

```
gulp.task('set-dev-node-env', function() {
    return process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
});
//dev environment run
gulp.task('default', ['set-dev-node-env', 'webpack-dev-server']);
```

When I run gulp and check the chromeconsole it says:

```
testing process.env.NODE_ENV undefined
```

What am I missing or how can I set this NODE_ENV variable? I would like to set it in the gulpfile somehow.

Here is the complete project: [github](https://github.com/dimitri-a/gulp_env)

Comment: You can't get NODE_ENV (server side) from Chrome console (client side).

Comment: ok, how can I get it then?

Comment: @elmeister Why not? Chrome can be used to debug Node; running an interactive session from a browser doesn't mean it isn't a representation of (via a proxy, much like a smarter version of dumb terminals of days of old) the current state of the server's process.

Comment: @user2864740 You are right, Chrome can be used to debug Node - but still you can't just open console (client side) and run shell commands (server side).

Comment: For gulp builds, gulp-mode plugin is simple to use. Details at [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68110717/10457393)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using WebPack you can use the [WebPack Define Plugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#defineplugin) to inject the `NODE_ENV`

For example in your webpack.config.dev.js:

```
module.exports = {
  ...

  plugins: [
    ...
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
    }),
  ],
};
```

Then in your react code you will have access to it `NODE_ENV` you set as `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

Comment: is there a reason you're json-stringifying a string? Does the string need to be escaped?

Comment: See the docs. Strings  are evaluated as code fragments. `JSON.stringify('development')` is setting the value to the string `development`. The other options are to use:  `"\"development\""`, `'\'development\''`, `'"development"'` or `"'development'"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using [gulp-env](https://github.com/crystalschang/gulp-env) module

```
// gulpfile.js

var gulp = require('gulp');
var env = require('gulp-env');

gulp.task('set-dev-node-env', function () {
  env({
    vars: {
      NODE_ENV: "development"
    }
  })
});

gulp.task('default', ['set-dev-node-env', 'webpack-dev-server'])
```