# process.env.NODE_ENV is set but still undefined

Tags: node.js, gulp, environment-variables

I need to pass a variable when calling gulp, so I one can manage different builds.
I am on Win7 and tried to set NODE_ENV like `set NODE_ENV=prod` .. then I start `gulp`

..in the gulpfile there is only a output

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
});
```

but process.env.NODE_ENV is always undefined(?)

```
[23:53:55] Using gulpfile F:\DevOps\gulpEnvTest\gulpfile.js
[23:53:55] Starting 'default'...
undefined
[23:53:55] The following tasks did not complete: default
[23:53:55] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Why is that? .. I also tried other things like cross-env, but this also does not work.

Comment: Another easier method to make boolean decisions is by using gulp-mode plugin, usage described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68110717/10457393).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt) when using `set NODE_ENV=prod` you are just setting it in the current process space.

You should use `setx NODE_ENV prod` to set the var to system environment variable level.

Comment: this is wierd.. when I do `setx NODE_ENV bla` in CMD.. then `gulp`.. it works,. when I do it in the CLI from VSCode, it doesn't .. but when I do `setx NODE_ENV bhop` in VSCode and then run `gulp` in CMD, it also works ..oO

Comment: When you're using `setx` you're setting this variable globally for the whole your system. So VSCode also reads it