# You should disable react-transform-hmr in production by using `env` section in Babel configuration

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I am using [babel-cli](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) for jsx and es6 features to transpile

i have changed my build command

from

```
"build": "node build",
```

to

`"build": "babel-node build"`,

Everything was working fine before

But when i run the build command i get this error

*Error: locals[0] does not appear to be a `module` object with Hot Module replacement API enabled. You should disable react-transform-hmr in production by using `env` section in Babel configuration. See the example in README: https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-hmr*

See the screenshot also

[image]

So i should disable react-transform-hmr in production by using `env` section in Babel configuration

and this is my .babelrc like the instructions

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        ["transform-object-rest-spread"],
        ["transform-react-display-name"],
        ["react-transform", {
          "transforms": [{
            "transform": "react-transform-hmr",
            "imports": ["react"],
            "locals": ["module"]
          }, {
            "transform": "react-transform-catch-errors",
            "imports": ["react", "redbox-react"]
          }]
        }]
      ]
    },
    "production": {
      "plugins": [
        ["transform-object-rest-spread"],
        ["transform-react-display-name"]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

what am i doing wrong? Any recommendation?

Comment: If you're using gulp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787457/how-can-i-set-an-environment-variable-from-gulp

Answer (score 3):

I had to add NODE_ENV=production to the command

```
"build": "NODE_ENV=production babel-node build"
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem at all, you just worked around it by not building a dev environment.